# Copy Stream to New File

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream

need to save a stream to a new File

Windows,.NET

```
        using (FileStream newFileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            await decryptedStream.CopyToAsync(newFileStream);
        }
```

Write to new file at FilePath . But receving error ;"cannot access closed file"

Comment: where is decryptedStream

Comment: Stream decryptedStream is already filled with data.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue.

The inputStream got disposed before it is set to copy to output filestream ;causing error "cannot access the closed file"